# How to change the Css class for a button when the button is clicked

Tags: css, asp.net, c#-4.0, button

i have a css class for a button in my .aspx page,i want to change cssclass for the button when it is clicked
i used the below code

```
`.btnmbl1
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: Black;
    font-family: Calibri;
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
    border-style: none;
    background-image: url(../images/Button_Mobile_R2.gif);
}
.btnmbl1:focus, .btnmbl1:hover
{
    background-image: url(../images/Button_Mobile_R2_1.gif);
}`
```

Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript on the client side (e.g. if there's no postback):

jQuery:

```
$("#buttonid").on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("btnmbl1").addClass("newClass");
}
```

On the server side, you can change the class in the click handler:

```
protected void button_click (object o, EventArgs e){
    //do stuff
    button.CssClass = "NewClass";
}
```